# How to compare two variables with columns from another table and execute code depending on if there is a match or no?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

The following code in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm declaring two variables `@AccID` and `@UserID` in this stored procedure which I want to use to compare them from another table called `OLD_Users` which has:

`AccountNUMBER`, `UserID1`, `UserID2`, `UserID3` columns.

Just like the `AccountNUMBER` and the 3 columns for user ids, both `@AccID` and `@UserID` are associated as well.
What I want to do is compare this `@AccID` and `@UserID` like this:

I want to make sure that `@AccID` matches with the `AccountNUMBER` from `OLD_Users` table and `@UserID` matches with any of the columns (`UserID1,UserID2,UserID3`) for this specific account - `@AccID`. 
If there is a match for both account id and user id then to continue executing the first code block where UserIDs starts with prefix `OLD..`. If there is no match then to execute the code block below where there is no `OLD` prefix on the UserIDs.

I am really not good at SQL stored procedures, so I am in need to ask you for a help. Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your expected outcome is. It is easy to do a comparison of values like you ask (just check that `accountumber = @accid and (userid1 = @userid or userid2 = @userid or userid3 = @userid)` in your table) but... I can't see where you're expecting this to happen in the code you pasted or what you expect the outcome to be if it doesn't match.

Comment: That's what I needed for the comparison. Thanks. Now I need to to do the following: If there is a match for the check/comparison you mentioned then to execute the first code block with the `OLD...` prefixes of the user ids, if there is no match then to execute the code block below. Like that: If there is a match for both @accid and @userid --> execute first block with all the 'if' statements and cases, if there is no match then execute the code from the second block again with all the 'if' statements and cases. Like combine these 2 code blocks into two main 'if' statements.

Comment: @ZLK - Actually I went to test it but ... `SELECT @UserID1 = UserID1, @UserID2 = UserID2, @UserID3 = UserID3 from OLD_Users WHERE AccountNUMBER = @AccID` So, if there is no match for the account then the checks `@userid1 = @userid or @userid2 = @userid or @userid3 = @userid` will simply return no match, right? No error if the outcome is `NULL` right? If so, only left the above to make the 2 code blocks into two main `if` statements for a match and no match.